# In AC circuits, angles and frequency are measured in radians rather than degrees. Why?

Tags: frequency, alternator, units

Why do we use radians instead of degrees when working with alternators and the like? The maximum induced EMF in an alternator will be a completely different value if one calculated ω in degrees per sec instead of radians per sec, so using radians as a measure isn't just for convenience as it appears to me.

Comment: Unit of measurement does not affect the result of calculations if all conversions are done properly.

As for why it is used - radian is the de-facto standard in math and physics so probably it was borrowed from there. Plus it is more natural unit for angles rather than something like degrees where humans arbitrary just decided to split full circle in 360 parts to be roughly equal to the number of days in a year.

Comment: @floppydisk The maximum emf is given by NBAω, so if ω is 360/ sec that will give a different answer to 2π/sec, where I went wrong?

Comment: In  that you have to convert degrees to radians before calculating.  The equation you used assumes radians, not degrees.

Comment: You did not correctly convert. If you use degrees as angles, your proportionality constants now obviously need to be some value times 1/°. So, as floppydisk said, you do need to convert.

Comment: Just as you won't have much fun with a policeman stopping you for driving twice the 50 km/h speed limit when you point out that you drive far less than 50 m/s. Three policeman follows the inequality $$\frac{v}{\frac{\text{km}}{\text{h}}}\le 50.$$ if your\$v\$ is not in km/h, you will need to convert the inequality or the speed.

Comment: If you were to use degrees for calculation you'd need a different formula which has appropriate coefficients. Part of why radians are so widely used is that all physics constants and other units are tailored to have 'nice' equations with standard units. That's nothing magical about radians themselves though, just so well it could be done with degrees or any other unit.

Comment: (@MarcusMüller *3.6 policemen follow*, to be exact)

Comment: @greybeard I manage to write TeX on my phone swipe keyboard, but of course fail at the very rare English word "the" instead of "three" 

Answer (score 4):

An angle is an angle. It does not matter what units you measure it in, as long as all conversion constants, speeds etc **are measured in the same units**.

Why do we have different units for angles? Each discipline that uses them tries to come up with a measure that works best for them. The reasons might be computational, or historical, or philosophical.

In mathematics, a natural measure is one where the length of the radius is used to measure distances round the circumference, the radian is the result.

Degrees possibly came from navigation, where halving an angle and constructing a 30 degree angle was easy. Or maybe from the Babylonians' love of 60 as a base for counting, dividing the easy to construct equilateral triangle. Either way, you get many small factors for the circle.

With electrical machines, I try to work with either one circle, aka a turn, or the pole pitch, as my natural basis for angle measure, both of which tend to convert more easily to degrees when I go to the calculator.

If you're working with a DSP to control motors, it's often useful to use a binary sub-division of a turn, perhaps 1/256th, as your smallest unit. As long as all your rate constants and lookup tables are scaled to use your newly defined angle measure, it will all work.

Answer (score 3):

There is only a scalar difference in using different units for angle or angular velocity. The *natural* unit is radians, since otherwise you'll end with a bunch of annoying constants. Of course you are free to use whatever units you like if that doesn't bother you. The answer should be exactly the same if the physical conditions are the same.

The natural unit for calculating sin(x) is radians using a typical algorithm, but typically calculators will convert degrees to radians for you before doing the calculation.

For example, angular momentum is Iω. Perhaps you'd like to use rotations/second or RPM or degrees per second. Then you'd have to insert constants of 2π, 2π/60, or 2π/360 respectively. That clutters up a nice clean easy-to-remember relationship.

Answer (score 2):

It's already mentioned in the comments, but the statement

> The maximum induced EMF in an alternator will be a completely different value if one calculated ω in degrees per sec instead of radians per sec

is incorrect.  It is incorrect because if you use the rotational velocity in radians per second, then you would use the EMF constant in units of volts per (radians per second), where if you use the rotational velocity in degrees per second, then you would use the EMF constant in units of volts per (degrees per second).  Normally you'd be expected to derive the one from the other, possibly in your head.

> Why do we use radians instead of degrees

I'm not sure who "we" is here.  You'll find that in practice, engineers tend to use radians and degrees, depending on what they're doing.  The more you lean toward the practical the more you'll be using degrees; the more you're doing mathematical analysis -- especially involving calculus -- the more you'll be using radians.

An engineering technician will never, or almost never, use radians, and can still do their job without knowing what they are.  An especially head-in-the-clouds applied mathematician may have some dim memory that these "degree" things are an alternative to radians, but may have to be prompted to remember how many degrees in a circle.

As a for-instance, you will almost always hear someone say that an inductor or capacitor has current that is 90 **degrees** out of phase with the voltage -- you almost never hear this as "pi over two radians" out of phase.

As another for-instance, if you look at DC brushed motor datasheets, the motor's back-EMF constant (if it's given at all) is almost universally given as volts per RPM, or volts per kilo-RPM.  This is even though the "natural" units for this is in volts per radians per second, which is a close match the torque constant in Newton-meters per amp (they are, in fact, identical numbers in an ideal motor; even the units match after a lot of manipulation).